# Keep getting accelerometer data when iPhone goes to sleep

Tags: ios, watchos

I am using CoreMotion and the CMMotionManager to get accelerometer data in my iOS and WatchOS app. It works fine except that it stops gathering data as soon the phone is locked.

Is it possible to keep getting the sensor updates while being locked ?

Comment: No, what you want isn't possible

Comment: Thank you @mag_zbc, how do you know it is not possible ?

Comment: Because the app's execution stops when it's sent to background, and there are no background modes that support getting accelerometer data

Comment: Ah thanks, I see, what about the application tracking sleep ? Can't they get the accelerometer data ?

Comment: I assume you mean with external device, like wearable heart monitor? If so, then it's possible - using `external-accessory` background mode

Comment: No I meant app like this one: https://itunes.apple.com/app/sleepbot-smart-cycle-alarm/id578829107?ign-mpt=uo%3D8 that works without external device